# Moodle load an external javascript file from URL

Tags: php, moodle

I am using Moodle 3.1+. I want to load javascript from an external URL into Moodle. I have tried adding it through config file of theme using

```
$THEME->javascripts_footer = array('pusher.min');
```

But is not working. I want to integrate Pusher into Moodle and for that, I have to load the script from URL 'https://js.pusher.com/3.2/pusher.min.js'.

Answer (score 1):

You may include library file like :

< script src="https://js.pusher.com/3.2/pusher.min.js"> in the footer file of your current theme.

It will load your library file.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$PAGE->requires->js('https://js.pusher.com/3.2/pusher.min.js',true);
```

I think it will work.